# BUILD BREAKER API query limit (30) reached

Tags: python, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarscanner

I am running a sonarQube analysis inside my gitlab runner, with the following config:

Sonarqube version: Version 7.9.1 (build 27448)

Gitlab-ci.yml:

```
Sonarqube:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: code analysis
  variables:
    SONAR_TOKEN: $SONAR_API_KEY
    SONAR_HOST_URL: $SONAR_URL
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=false -Dsonar.projectKey=$CI_PROJECT_NAME -Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml -Dsonar.sources=app/ -Dsonar.tests=tests/
```

I am using a Sonarqube instance from my company and cannot change any plug-ins or anything. I am getting the following error from my runner logs:

```
 INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
 INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
 ERROR: [BUILD BREAKER] API query limit (30) reached.  Try increasing sonar.buildbreaker.queryMaxAttempts, sonar.buildbreaker.queryInterval, or both.
```

The report is avaibable at the url that it's trying to reach...

Is there a way to disable this plug-in from the commandline or anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this later, I found the solution.

According to https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/ only sonar-scanner version 4.0 is compatible.

The docker image with version 4.1 (https://hub.docker.com/layers/sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli) works fine though.